# Query user logins using distinct and reprot back daily, weekly and monthly usage

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Query, that I'm looking to report back site usage hourly, daily, weekly and monthly.

I require the query to use Distinct as the nature of the application will create several entries to the table upon a each new login to the site.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT OPRID, 
CONVERT(varchar(12), LOGINDTTM, 112) 'Date'
from   PSACCESSLOG_HIST
where  OPRID NOT IN ('AUTOPROC', 'PSAPPS', 'PHSADBA', 'PTWEBSERVER')
ORDER BY Date
```

This will give the following:

```
OPRID     LOGIPADDRESS     LOGINDTTM      LOGOUTDTTM
dadams     10.1.1.5        20130612        20130612
jblake     10.1.1.5        20130614        20130614
```

First I do need to group the data as mentioned above by day. This is what I'm looking for, for this part:

```
LOGINDATE-TIME    TOTAL-LOGINS
20130612           25
20130613           35
20130614           45
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(12), LOGINDTTM, 112) 'Date', count(*) as TOTAL-LOGINS
from PSACCESSLOG_HIST
where OPRID NOT IN ('AUTOPROC', 'PSAPPS', 'PHSADBA', 'PTWEBSERVER')
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: Can you expand on why your proposed solution resolves the issue?

Comment: Thanks this gave me what I was looking for.  Incidentally do you know what parameter I need to convert to show hours as well

Comment: No, I don't know off the top of my head. But you can easily google that.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me how your query results in the table you produce.  Your query does not mention `logoutdttm`.  In any case, you can do what you want by grouping by date and counting the distinct "OPRID"s on each date (if I understand your request correctly):

```
SELECT  CONVERT(varchar(12), LOGINDTTM, 112) as "Date", count(distinct OPRID) as NumOPRs
from   PSACCESSLOG_HIST
where  OPRID NOT IN ('AUTOPROC', 'PSAPPS', 'PHSADBA', 'PTWEBSERVER')
group by CONVERT(varchar(12), LOGINDTTM, 112)
ORDER BY Date
```

(As a side note, SQL Server doesn't allow you to use an alias in the `group by` column.)

Instead of the `convert()`, I prefer converting the date time to a `date` data type:

```
SELECT  cast(LOGINDTTM as date) as "Date", count(distinct OPRID) as NumOPRs
from   PSACCESSLOG_HIST
where  OPRID NOT IN ('AUTOPROC', 'PSAPPS', 'PHSADBA', 'PTWEBSERVER')
group by cast(LOGINDTTM as date)
ORDER BY "Date"
```

Also, although SQL Server may allow you to put the aliases for columns in single quotes, you should use double quotes or square brackets.  Single quotes have a strong meaning as a constant string in a SQL statement, and not as the name of a column or table.